# How to pull the current user's email and insert into a script placeholder?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using an affiliate tracker called Rewardful, and it requires me to pass the users email to this script

```
<script>
rewardful('convert', { email: 'email@goeshere.com' })
</script>
```

The rewardful script is third party hosted by them, so I cannot modify this.

I have found some script to pull/echo the current user's email but I cannot figure out how to insert it into the placeholder of another script.

I have no idea if this matters in terms of how this question is answered, but this script will only be used on one page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the email in a HTML tag inside your output (via PHP).

```
<div data-email="foo@bar.com"></div>
```

Then from Javascript side pull it out.

```
rewardful('convert', { email: document.querySelector("div[data-email]").dataset.email; })
```

This selector will find the element and extract the attributes value `foo@bar.com`.